# Почему этот код работает неправильно

Tags: python, операторы

Почему этот код работает неправильно (если не учитывать, что у него не установлены ограничения на ввод букв и т.д. ), почему не выдает ответ к примеру "меланхолик и флегматик ", а выдает просто "флегматик"?

```
    i=int(input('i'))
    ii=int(input('ii'))
    iii=int(input('iii'))
    iiii=int(input('iiii'))
    sum=i+ii+iii+iiii
    h=i/sum*100
    s=ii/sum*100
    f=iii/sum*100
    m=iiii/sum*100

    if h>(s or f or m):
        print('Вы холерик')
    elif s>(h or f or m):
        print('Вы сангвиник')
    elif f>(h or s or m):
        print('Вы флегматик')
    elif m>(s or f or h):
        print('Вы меланхолик')
    elif s==h and s >(f or m):
        print('Вы сангвиник и холерик')
    elif f==h and f >(s or m):
        print('Вы флегматик и холерик')
    elif m==h and m >(f or s):
        print('Вы меланхолик и холерик')
    elif m==s and s >(f or h):
        print('Вы меланхолик и сангвиник')
    elif f==s and f >(h or m):
        print('Вы флегматик и сангвиник')
    elif m==f and m >(h or s):
        print('Вы флегматик и меланхолик')
```

Comment: `(s or f or m)` - это Вы где такое видели?

Comment: Код работает правильно. Неправильно написаны условия. ``h>(s or f or m)`` - проверяет совсем не то, что вам кажется.

Comment: а что он проверяет тогда, не понимаю?